# Android - getAllCellInfo() returns corruped values

Tags: java, android, signal-strength, cellinfo

I have to implement an android application to get information about the cellular network, like signal strength, cellId and radio access technologie.

My implementation is close to this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38176434/7822319. I just added the parameter ASU to each technology.

I have a similar problem like mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800290/lte-signal-asu-level-always-97?answertab=votes#tab-top) with my Lenovo Tab2 A10-70L with Android 5.0.1. The method getAllCellInfo() seems to return wrong values.

The dBm value varies around 400 dBm. The ASU level is always at 97. 
The SIM-Status in the android settings shows the supposed right values -98dBm and 42ASU.

Does anybody know a solution for this problem ? Or is there a way to get these values on another way ?

Thanks in advance.